# Merge dicts in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, object

Say I have a list of dictionaries in python like such:

```
[{"key": "a", "prop1": "alpha"}, {"key": "a", "prop2": "beta"}, {"key": "b", "prop1": "alpha"}]
```

How would I merge the dicts so the list becomes:

```
[{"key": "a", "prop1": "alpha", "prop2": "beta"}, {"key": "b", "prop1": "alpha"}]
```

Comment: Note those are _dictionaries_ in Python. What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: It seems what you are trying to do is merge dictionaries, not list objects

Comment: Thanks, edited. I create a new list, loop through all the dicts an add the object to it if the key doesn't exist or update the objects with the new prop is the key exists. It works but not efficient for big lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.update`:

```
lst = [
    {"key": "a", "prop1": "alpha"},
    {"key": "a", "prop2": "beta"},
    {"key": "b", "prop1": "alpha"},
]

out = {}
for d in lst:
    out.setdefault(d["key"], {}).update(d)

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```
[{'key': 'a', 'prop1': 'alpha', 'prop2': 'beta'}, {'key': 'b', 'prop1': 'alpha'}]
```